# How to Show Dialog in Android if the User press the (Physical) Back Button

Tags: java, android

Please can you teach me and explain on How to Show the Message Dialog in Android if the User press the (Physical) Back Button

and something will pop up and ask the user DO YOU WANT TO EXIT? and the application ask yes if YES OR NO.

Answer (score 1):

You can just override your `onBackPressed()` method of your activity, and do whatever you want do on back press of device.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setMessage("DO YOU WANT TO EXIT?")
            .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                 }
             })
             .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 }
             }).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override [Activity.onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) in your activity to get custom functionality.

Edit: To create your Yes/No dialog look into using a [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) to create you dialog and assign callbacks for the Yes/No buttons.